# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in models with a has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I have two models

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_information
  attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

UserInformation Model

```
class UserInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :address, :business, :phone
end
```

I create a user record and everthing works fine, but when I try to create the user information I get this this error:

> ```
> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UserInformationsController#create
>
> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
> ```

To create the user information record I go to

> localhost:3000/users/1/user_informations/new

and fill the form. Then I get the error.

Please I need help I'm trying to do this for the last 4 days and now I desperate

Thank you very much for your help.

---

The user information form

```
<%= form_for(@user_information) do |f| %>
  <% if @user_information.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user_information.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user_information from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user_information.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :business %><br />
    <%= f.check_box :business %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

the user_information_controller

```
class UserInformationsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /user_informations
  # GET /user_informations.json
  def index
    @user_informations = UserInformation.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_informations }
    end
  end

  # GET /user_informations/1
  # GET /user_informations/1.json
  def show
    @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_information }
    end
  end

  # GET /user_informations/new
  # GET /user_informations/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_information = UserInformation.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_information }
    end
  end

  # GET /user_informations/1/edit
  def edit
    @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /user_informations
  # POST /user_informations.json
  def create
    @user_information = UserInformation.new(params[:user_information])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_information.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user_information, notice: 'User information was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user_information, status: :created, location: @user_information }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /user_informations/1
  # PUT /user_informations/1.json
  def update
    @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_information.update_attributes(params[:user_information])
        format.html { redirect_to @user_information, notice: 'User information was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user_information.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /user_informations/1
  # DELETE /user_informations/1.json
  def destroy
    @user_information = UserInformation.find(params[:id])
    @user_information.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to user_informations_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In UserInformation Model,

Add user to the attr_accessible

```
attr_accessible :address, :business, :phone, :user
```

Comment: Hey wasi, thanks for your help. I already try this but with this change I get this error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in UserInformationsController#create
User(#70283633984760) expected, got String(#70283616837500)

Comment: Hey Jean, how are you creating Userinformaions in the controller?

Comment: try renaming the user column to user_id column. Rails can't pass an object as a parameter. It replaces the object with its id if it has one or just passes a string representation of the object

Comment: so in your case it is just passing a string.

Comment: I'm sorry but know I get this error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user_id, I only change :user to :user_id in the form

Comment: I tried to create the form_for like this <%= form_for([@user_information, @user.user_information.bluild]) do |f| %> but it doesn't work, I only need help with the form_for creation

Comment: I meant renaming the user column in the database to user_id. Add <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %> in the form. 
and attr_accessible :address, :business, :phone, :user_id in your Userinformation model

and finally add @user_information = current_user.user_informations.build in your User Controller

Comment: Oh man, now I get undefined method `user_informations' for #<User:0x007fe37d260198>

Comment: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass 
T.T

Comment: looks like current_user is nil. You might have not written to find method current_user. This can be helpful http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/205334

Comment: But in the params I have {"id"=>"1"}

Comment: If you want to use the user based on the id passed in do `@user.user_information.build` in the `new` action.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried. 
user = User.find(params[:id])
@user_information = user.user_information.build

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem change it the new action in the user_information controller like this:

```
def new
         @user = User.find(params[:id])
         @user_information = @user.build_user_information

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user_information }
    end
  end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a form for user_information including fields of user. If that's what you want, you should build a nested form for user including the user_informations.
Then if the user is updated, the user_informations will be too.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :name

    has_one :user_information
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_information
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for @user ..
    ...
    <%= fields_for :user_information do |b| %>
        <%= b.text_field ...
```

Check http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/